# IsDebugEnabled vs. Debug(Action<FormatMessageHandler>)

Tags: .net, logging, lambda

[In common logging V2.0](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) there are two methods of avoiding costs of message evaluation when LogLevel is higher than the log entry:

```
if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
    Log.Debug("Debug message");
```

or

```
Log.Debug(a => a("Debug message"));
```

Which practice is better? What are the pros & cons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to documentation:

> Leveraging lambdas, the ILog interface
>   offers a new & safe way to write log
>   statements

```
log.Debug( m=>m("value= {0}", obj.Value) );
```

> This ensures, that the whole expression is only evaluated when
>   LogLevel.Debug is enabled and thus
>   saves you from having to write

```
if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    log.Debug("value={0}", obj.Value);
}
```

> to avoid this overhead.

So the second option in your quesetion considered a best practice.